# How to Detect Collide with Random Generated Sprite AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

First sorry for my bad english... 

The Scenario:
I have load 3 kind of sprite
1. Player
2. Obstacle (Generate Random X Coordinate)
3. Rectangle (Obstacle child)

I've created auto generate obstacle for every second, After generated the obstacle will fall down with the gravity.
Every obstacle have rectangle as its child. I'll use this rectangle to detect collision with player.
If player collide with this rectangle i need to change the score, and if the player hit the obstacle i need to kill the player

```
_scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.5f, true, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            int _coorx = randInt(0,_constants.CAMERA_WIDTH);

            // OBSTACLE
            _obstacle = new Sprite(_coorx, -50, _obstacletr, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            _obstaclefd = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            _obstaclebody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(_physicsworld, _obstacle, BodyType.DynamicBody, _obstaclefd);
            _physicsworld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(_obstacle, _obstaclebody, true, false));

            // OBSTACLE RECTANGLE
            _obstaclerectangle = new Rectangle(-_coorx, 0, _constants.CAMERA_WIDTH, 5, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            _obstaclerectangle.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    if(_obstaclerectangle.collidesWith(_player1)) {
                        _obstaclerectangle.setColor(1, 0, 0);
                    } else {
                        _obstaclerectangle.setColor(0, 1, 0);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void reset() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
            _obstacle.attachChild(_obstaclerectangle);

            _scene.attachChild(_obstacle);
        }

    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a ContactListener.

Create a collider class that implements ContactListener:

```
public class Collider implements ContactListener {...}
```

Then add the collider class as to the world:

```
youPhysicworld.setContactListener(collider);
```

In the class Collider you are force to implement the methods that will be called whenever a physic event (beginContact, endCOntact, preSolve, postSolve) happens.
In these methods you can handle the events as you wish.

Comment: already solved.. I used array to save the sprite and onUpdate detect all object by checking on array indexes. But thank's for your solution i can use it for other problems